# Jquery .data keeps going undefined on draggable element in droppable area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I been struggling with this all morning and I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.  On my page I have a draggable text field.  (It has a static ID for testing purposes when you first drag it to the canvas as "item-text-1")

When I first drag the item down in the console log you can clearly see a "1" being outputed from the $("#item-text-1").data("test")  however as you continue to drag it around a few times, it will start to go to "undefined" for some reason and I have absolutely no idea how to fix this.  I tried doing ui.helper.detached() then also removed that all together and I'm just lost at this point.

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( function() {

    function setDraggable(el, doClone) {
        el.draggable({
            helper: doClone ? 'clone' : "original"
        });
    }

$(".pages").droppable({
  accept: ".draggable",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    cloned = ui.helper.clone();
     cloned.removeClass('ui-resizable');
    var applyData = false;
    if (ui.draggable.hasClass('cloned') == false) {
         applyData = true;
          console.log("this is a clone!");
          cloned.addClass('cloned');
      }
                 cloned.find(".ui-resizable-handle").remove();
                 cloned.find(".ui-resizable").remove();
                 cloned.find("resizable").remove();
                 cloned.removeClass('ui-resizable');
          cloned.resizable().draggable();

    setDraggable(cloned, false)
    cloned.attr("id", "item-text-1");

    $( this )
    .append(cloned)

    if (applyData == true) {
        $("#item-text-1").data("test", "1");
         console.log($("#item-text-1").data("test"));
    } else {
        console.log($("#item-text-1").data("test"));
    }

      var newTop = $(ui.helper).offset().top - $(this).offset().top;
      var newLeft = $(ui.helper).offset().left - $(this).offset().left;

      cloned.css("top", newTop);
       cloned.css("left", newLeft);

    //ui.helper.detach();
  }
});
$(".pagesWrapper").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.helper.remove();
  }
})
setDraggable($(".draggable"), true);

    $( "#tab-container" ).tabs();
    } );

    </script>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center; margin: 0;">

<div id="template-container" style="width: 880px; height: 775px; background-color: #f3f3f3; margin: auto; border: 3px solid #636363; padding: 8px;">

    <div id="roles-tabs" style="padding-left: 0px; height: 90px; width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">
        <div id="button-container" style="float: left; width: 60px; height: 80px; display: block;">&nbsp;</div>

            <div id="tab-container" style="width: 600px; float: left; padding-right: 5px; padding-top: 5px; height: 80px;">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-formfields">Data Fields</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div id="tabs-formfields">
              <table>
              <tbody>
              <tr>
              <td style="padding-right: 6px;">
                <div id="item-textfield" name="item-textfield" class="items-textfield draggable draggable-item" style="width: 100px; height: 30px; cursor: pointer; background-color: black; color: white; z-index: 99999">
                    <div class="new-textfield-field">
                        <div class="fake-data">Text Field</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>

              </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div id="showPDF" class="pdf-container pagesWrapper" style="z-index: 0; padding-top: 50px; width: 880px; padding-bottom: 50px; height: 515px; overflow-y: auto; background-color: #565656;">
        <div style="margin: auto;" class="canvas">

        <div id="page1" class="pages" style="position: relative; margin: auto; width: 400px; height: 500px; background-color: white;">

                </div><br /><br />

            </div>


    </div>
    <br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here's why the current implementation is not working:
You have two droppable areas:

```
$(".pages").droppable({
...
and
$(".pagesWrapper").droppable({
```

1. When you drag the element the first time, a clone is created by jquery ui and dropped into the page container. Let's say clone "no-id". Then in the page droppable, the "no-id" is again cloned by this

   cloned = ui.helper.clone();
   ...
   cloned.attr("id", "item-text-1");

Now you have on the dom two elements "no-id" and "item-text-1".
When you assign the data to the element by id "item-text-1" this data will be assigned to the single element with that id.

After this handler finishes, you have the second droppable handler, that will also perform his logic upon the "no-id" element and remove it from the dom.

ui.helper.remove();

Now you have only one clone remaining : "item-text-1".

2. When you drag the remaining clone the second time you will create another clone because of the page droppable handler, and you will have two elements with the id "item-text-1".

When you display now the data in the "item-text-1" element, because byId will return the first occurrence, you will see the data set before, in the first drag. The second element has no data attached to it.

When the pagesWrapper droppable will be invoked, then first element with the id "item-text-1" will be removed, and you will only have the last element available in the dom, that does not have the data anymore.

And from here on the data is lost.

In order to preserve the data, you will need to assign it to the new object after you clone the source object:

```
cloned = ui.helper.clone();
cloned.data('test', ui.helper.data('test'));
```

In this way you will always have the data with you, but be aware that your text control is always a new one, not the original clone.

Comment: I have to use .data because there are over 50 items bound by .data but even one is being set as undefined

Comment: The access to the data is done in the same way : $("#item-text-1").data("test"). Basically the change does the same thing but if that's not an option I'll check a bit more

Comment: I have added a better answer describing your problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand now, I never thought that pagesWrapper would be causing an invoke since it was the part behind the actual droppable its being dropped into.  From your answer I also was able to find out about just doing cloned.data(ui.helper,data()); to copy everything over.  Thank you very VERY much for your in-depth explanation helped me understand droppable a lot more.  Also I found for my main droppable to make sure to use greedy: true -> http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-greedy